Create Calculated Member Status %
I have a cube which is a small log of telephone zones,

measure -> [Measures].[Calls Count]
dimension -> [CallStatus].[Status2].[Status].&[Busy]
[CallStatus].[Status2].[Status].&[Invalid]
[CallStatus].[Status2].[Status].&[Successful]
[CallStatus].[Status2].[Status].&[Timeout]
[CallStatus].[Status2].[Status].&[Unknow]
[CallStatus].[Status2].[Status].&[Unsuccessful]

based on this data I need to create Calculated Member Status% which will calculate the percentage of call statuses
Case When IsEmpty( [Measures].[Call Count] ) 
     Then 0 
      Else 
              ([Measures].[Calls Count],[CallStatus].[CallsStatus].CurrentMember)
            / SUM( [CallStatus].[Status2].[Status].Members, [Measures].[Calls Count] ) 
End

but Grand Total always shows 1(100%) statuses and not the sum of the selected statuses

